# Looking for multisig wallet source code?

Tags: wallets, contract-deployment, multisignature

Found several multisig wallet source codes but I can't deploy them in ethereum wallet because they can't be compiled. Either they use an old version of solidity or I get the error "No visibility specified."

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ethereum/dapp-bin/master/wallet/wallet.sol

https://github.com/gnosis/MultiSigWallet/blob/master/contracts/MultiSigWallet.sol

Comment: make sure these sources are bug free. You certainly don't want to live the experience of Parity users.

Comment: I know, that's also why I am asking this. I need a contract that can be trusted.

Answer (score 1):

You can give this a try https://github.com/ConsenSys/MultiSigWallet
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I like this one:

```
https://github.com/kinfoundation/kin-token/blob/master/test/MultiSigWallet.js
```

Im working developing one of them. To be honest its better to try to use one of the zeppelin or gnosis instead of create your own because its more risky if anything goes wrong.